# shortening a calculator in python

Tags: python

I have managed to create a small calculator in Python, but I am trying to shorten the code unsucsessfully. Can anyone help please?

```
elif queencommand == "/calc addition" :
    num1 = input("Enter first number")
    num2 = input("Enter second number")
    Answer = (int(num1) + int(num2))
    input(Answer)
elif queencommand == "/calc subtraction" :
    num1 = input("Enter first number")
    num2 = input("Enter second number")
    Answer = (int(num1) - int(num2))
    input(Answer)
elif queencommand == "/calc multiplication" :
    num1 = input("Enter first number")
    num2 = input("Enter second number")
    Answer = (int(num1) * int(num2))
    input(Answer)
elif queencommand == "/calc division" :
    num1 = input("Enter first number")
    num2 = input("Enter second number")
    Answer = (int(num1) / int(num2))
    input(Answer)
```

I am not able to do two operations at once either.

Comment: Your code looks incomplete, I doubt it should start with an elif.

Comment: When asking a question, try to make the code stand-alone. You could have made the first `elif` a simple `if`, since the other branches preceding this part of the code clearly don't matter to your question.

Comment: It is. This is merely a command within a program.

Answer (score 1):

Use functions from the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) or simple functions you define yourself to the calculation work, then map the operation name from the `queencommand` string to those functions:

```
import operator

ops = {
    'addition': operator.add,
    'subtraction': operator.sub,
    'multiplication': operator.mul,
    'division': operator.truediv
}
if queencommand.startswith("/calc"):
    operation = queencommand.partition(' ')[-1]
    if operation in ops:
        num1 = input("Enter first number")
        num2 = input("Enter second number")
        Answer = ops[operation](int(num1), int(num2))
```

`operator.add` could be replaced by `lambda a, b: a + b`, etc. if you don't want to use a module for those operations.

Comment: I have tried that but if I enter /calc it simply stops the entire application.

Comment: @notevenslightlyapcgod: that wasn't part of your original question. Your current code doesn't handle `"/calc"` either. Your code and mine both expect you to enter `"/calc addition"` or `"/calc multiplicition"`.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully fledged calculator. See if it helps:

```
    def multiplication():
      num1 = int(input("First #: "))
      num2 = int(input("Second #: "))
      ans = num1 * num2
      print(ans)

    def addition():
      num1 = int(input("First #: "))
      num2 = int(input("Second #: "))
      ans = num1 + num2
      print(ans)


    def subtraction():
      num1 = int(input("First #: "))
      num2 = int(input("Second #: "))
      ans = num1 - num2
      print(ans)


    def division():
      num1 = int(input("First #: "))
      num2 = int(input("Second #: "))
      ans = num1 / num2
      print(ans)


    def Help():
      print("""Welcome to Calculator P1!!!       
      Type "x" for multiplication.
      Type "+" for addition.
      Type "-" for subtraction.
      Type "/" for division.""")


    while True:
      print("Type 'help' for introduction or instructions")
      choice = input("Operator: ")

      if choice == "x" or choice == "muliplication":
        multiplication()

      elif choice == "+" or choice == "addition":
        addition()

      elif choice == "-" or choice == "subtraction":
        subtraction()

      elif choice == "/" or choice == "division":
        division()

      elif choice == "help":
        Help()


      answer = input('Run again? (y/n): ')
      if answer == 'n':
        break
      elif answer == 'y':
        continue
      else:
        print("""Unrecognized Input.
                       <<<<RESTARTING PROGRAM>>>>""")
        continue
```